# Best place to store static error strings

Tags: c#, exception, standards

I was wondering if anyone had any input on the best practice of where to store static error strings in a C# application. I have a visual studio 2010 solution that has 5 projects and have defined several constant error messages to be returned via a WCF REST web service in the form of a message.

My current errors I have defined (hard-coded) are in the following format (CODE, MESSAGE):

999   -       Your request could not be processed with the parameters specified.

I am not asking how to create custom classes derived from the Exception class because these errors are returned after corresponding Exceptions are raised to keep the AppPool from faulting.

Some ideas I was pondering storing the messages in: XML, Flat File, SQLite, and so on.

Does anyone have a preference and if so, why?

Thank you,

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally store these things in the projects [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) file, and then retrieve them when I need them.  Doing it this way also makes it a lot easier to change them, for example if you needed the system to use another language all you'd do is switch the resources file for one in another language and voila!

Comment: I have thought about this as well. I like your point about the languages. However, I am unable to use a number as a name in the resources file. How do you normally go about naming your entries for error messages? Thanks!

Comment: I usually have a name that makes the message obvious, like ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND but in your case you could use ERROR_123 like that.  You could even write a manager for the resources, that given an error number would be able to retrieve the appropriate error message to give the same result

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Answered! Thanks for your help!