# Best place to store saved messages

Tags: c#, class, console-application

I am currently creating a console applications that only accepts some commands defined by me. The thing is I'm storing a lot of error and notification messages on a static class I created called Messages and then just calling them like Messages.ErrorMessage.... ErrorMessage is just a static string that contains w/e I want printed on the console.
What I wanted to ask is if that's a good way of implementing such behavior or should I instead change where I'm keeping all of this Messages?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Static classes are in fact always bad behavior. Such design tends to become error-prone and has a lot of side effects. You can store the messages in a dedicated class. You create a instance of that class and it is uses as a parameter that is passed through the entire program. A **Singleton** instance is in many design patterns books seens as an anti-pattern.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a Resource file: http://stackoverflow.com/q/90697/7586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess for your need you can use **Resource file** instead of static class.

as documented on official site

> Visual C# applications often include data that is not source code.
>   Such data is referred to as a project resource and it can include
>   binary data, text files, audio or video files, string tables, icons,
>   images, XML files, or any other type of data that your application
>   requires. Project resource data is stored in XML format in the .resx
>   file (named Resources.resx by default) which can be opened in Solution
>   Explorer.

For more information :-

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: So far I've being told to either use resource files or just create a regular class for handling messages... What's the best approach?

Comment: @AlonsoQuesada have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134018/what-are-the-benefits-of-resource-resx-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370921/best-place-to-store-static-error-strings?rq=1

Comment: Ill try resource files then... thanks for your quick response and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, storing them in resource files is the recommended way to deal with such resources, particularly if you'll need to deal with internationalization. then you can load a different resource file from a satellite assembly at run time with the correct information.

You will notice a slight performance hit as the strings will be looked up in a resource dictionary, but usually that is negligible.

Comment: So far I've being told to either use resource files or just create a regular class for handling messages... What's the best approach?

Comment: The resource files are the best approach IMO